# Merging 2 lists while retaining the original data

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I wasn't sure how exactly to word the title but this is the situation.  I have 2 lists,  `DBList` is a list of DB values and `NewList` is the new list of values to be stored in the DB.  Now the tricky part is that I am only adding values to `DBList` that don't already exist, BUT if `DBList` contains values that `NewList` doesn't then i want to remove them

Essentially, `NewList` becomes `DBList` but i want to retain all the applicable previously existing data in `DBList` that is already persisted to the database

This is what I have and it works, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
    List<DeptMajors> DBList;
    List<DeptMajors> NewList;
    for(DeptMajors dm : NewList) {
        if(!DBList.contains(dm)) {
            DBList.add(dm);
        }
    }

    Iterator<DeptMajors> i = DBList.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        DeptMajors dm = i.next();
        if(!NewList.contains(dm)) {
            i.remove()
        }
    }
```

So the first loops puts all data from `NewList` into `DBList` that doesn't already exist.  Then the next loop will check if `DBList` contains data that doesn't exist in `NewList` and removes it from `DBList`

Comment: At the end element in both the list will be same.Where are you retaining "all the applicable previously existing data in DBList that is already persisted to the database"?

Comment: List<DeptMajors>newNBList = NewList.collect {DBList.contains(it)?DBList.get(it):it}

Comment: @BZ. Think you mean `newList.collect { e -> dbList.contains(e) ? dbList.find { it == e }: e}` which does indeed work as well :-)

Comment: @BZ. Also, `newList.collect { e -> dbList.find { it == e } ?: e}` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I had to make up a `DeptMajors` class:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@TupleConstructor
@ToString(includeNames=true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes=['id'])
class DeptMajors {
    int id
    String name
    int age
}
```

This class is equal if the `id` matches (and no other fields)

We can then make a `dbList` (lower case initial char for variables, else Groovy can sometimes get confused and think it's a class)

```
def dbList = [
    new DeptMajors(1, 'tim', 21),
    new DeptMajors(2, 'raymond', 20)
]
```

And a `newList` which contains an updated `raymond` (which will be ignored), a new entry `alice` (which will be added) and no `tim` (so that will be removed)

```
def newList = [
    new DeptMajors(2, 'raymond', 30),
    new DeptMajors(3, 'alice', 28)
]
```

We can then work out our new merged list.  This is the intersection of `dbList` and `newList` (so we keep `raymond` in the original state), added to the new elements in `newList` which can be found by taking `dbList` away from it:

```
def mergedList = dbList.intersect(newList) + (newList - dbList)
```

This give the result I think you want?

```
assert mergedList == [
    new DeptMajors(2, 'raymond', 20),  // unchanged
    new DeptMajors(3, 'alice', 28)     // new entry (tim is removed)
]
```

### Edit

Or as BZ says in the comments, you could also use:

```
def mergedList = newList.collect { e -> dbList.contains(e) ? dbList.find { it == e }: e}
```

Or the shorter:

```
def mergedList = newList.collect { e -> dbList.find { it == e } ?: e}
```

Comment: yes you are correct in the result that I want, the code you provided did not work for me.  But the modified version of @BZ code you provided did work.  So I am not sure who to give credit to.

Comment: BZ didn't post an answer, so I guess it's a case of you snooze, you lose ;-)

Comment: It's all good :)  You corrected my answer since I was just typing in a comment box.